# Android : Refresh View location after TranslateAnimation?

Tags: android, animation, view, position

I'm using a TranslateAnimation to move an ImageView from 0,0 to 200,0 for example

When onAnimationEnd occured, i need a way to get the new position of the ImageView. I tried getLocationInWindow(), getLocationOnScreen() and getLeft() methods but the position is never refreshed.

Here is the result of the code bellow :

```
02-03 13:18:03.600: E/test(22898): onAnimationStart !
02-03 13:18:03.600: E/test(22898): getLocationInWindow : 90 , 70
02-03 13:18:03.600: E/test(22898): getLocationOnScreen : 90 , 70
02-03 13:18:03.600: E/test(22898): getLeft : 0
02-03 13:18:06.590: E/test(22898): onAnimationEnd !
02-03 13:18:06.590: E/test(22898): getLocationInWindow : 90 , 70
02-03 13:18:06.590: E/test(22898): getLocationOnScreen : 90 , 70
02-03 13:18:06.590: E/test(22898): getLeft : 0


final TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0, 0);
        ta.setDuration(3000);
        ta.setFillAfter(true);
        ivCurseurMoyenneComportement.startAnimation(ta);

        ta.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(final Animation arg0) {
                Log.e("test", "onAnimationStart !");
                final int[] loc = new int[2];
                ivCurseurMoyenneComportement.getLocationInWindow(loc);
                Log.e("test", "getLocationInWindow : " + loc[0] + " , "
                        + loc[1]);
                ivCurseurMoyenneComportement.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
                Log.e("test", "getLocationOnScreen : " + loc[0] + " , "
                        + loc[1]);
                Log.e("test",
                        "getLeft : "
                                + ivCurseurMoyenneComportement.getLeft());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation arg0) {
                Log.e("test", "onAnimationEnd !");
                final int[] loc = new int[2];
                ivCurseurMoyenneComportement.getLocationInWindow(loc);
                Log.e("test", "getLocationInWindow : " + loc[0] + " , "
                        + loc[1]);
                ivCurseurMoyenneComportement.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
                Log.e("test", "getLocationOnScreen : " + loc[0] + " , "
                        + loc[1]);
                Log.e("test",
                        "getLeft : "
                                + ivCurseurMoyenneComportement.getLeft());
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You get the position of the view - which is not moved and thus does not change.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, I am facing the exact same issue?